# Calling function before changing viewport shading

Tags: python

Is it possible to execute code right before changing the 3D Viewport shading mode?
I know about bpy.app.handlers to register functions on certain events, but changing viewport shading does not exist there.
Specifically, I would like to execute code whenever the viewport shading is set to 'Rendered'.